# how to request a script more than once in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Can I ask how I can request a script more than once in wordpress. For example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2 ; $i++){
wp_enqueue_script('alerthello.js', 'example.com/example.js');
}
```

I expect the code to display two hello, but it display one only instead.

Comment: The function name is `wp_enqueue_script`, not `wp_enquece`.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

PS: I see an infinite loop up there

Answer (score 0):

Because the script name is the same WordPress will only add that script once.  The `wp_enqueue_script` function just adds scripts to a queue and if there are two of the same scripts it will only spit out one.

I don't know why you would want to have the same script added more than once, but you can try this.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2 ; $i++){
    wp_enqueue_script('alerthello.js'.$i, 'example.com/example.js');
}
```

Also you can check out the wp_print_scripts() http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_scripts